# android: implementation and make listener to a socket

Tags: android, service, sockets, listener

i'm devlopping an application for android,

i need to make a session between client(cell phone) and e web server (apache)
and keep alive this session to receive notification from the server 
for this i may implement socket also make a listener for this socket to notify the client if a file is ready to download, after receiving this notifcation (the ID of the file) the client will download this file

so my question is, it's possible to implement that?
the best solution is to use sockets or web service
can you fill me some links or tutorials that's helps me to implement that

thank you so much